# Display tables inside each day in angular-ui-calendar

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, ui-calendar

I have a use case where I just need the calendar skeleton and month switching capabilities, but inside each day, I need to place some custom built tables (signup slots for shifts) instead of the standard events. Is there a way to do that with ui-calendar somehow? Or am I limited to the default event structure?

Thanks.

Comment: Since it;s a wrapper for jQuery fullcalendar you can inject html within the event rendering callbacks but using tables of any size may not be very effective. I would suggest playing with a standalone jQuery version to see what happens first as it will be simpler to work with for testing your idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a better alternative with the [Angular Bootstrap Calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar). In addition to having about the same functionality, it also allows for [custom cell templates](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-calendar/#?example=custom-templates) which is just what I need in my use case.